# Upload gallery by ftp

Tags: views, media, files

Is there a module for drupal7 that can create galleries from ftp? basically I upload a bunch of folders containing images in them by ftp. I want drupal to auto populate from ftp to create galleries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [himuesgallery](http://drupal.org/project/himuesgallery) module?

> It implements a new node-type to show all pictures in an specified directory. Descriptions will be automatically generated from the filenames, so there is no need to administer a seperate databse table, etc.
>   My gallery works with automated generetated thumbnails so it seems to be fast.
>   It can use Lightbox2 or colorbox to simply generate lightshows and naturally it makes use of user configurable css-files to style the gallery. Some styles will be delivered with the module, so users don't be worried about this.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Media Mover](http://drupal.org/project/media_mover)

> Media Mover is a set of modules which allows website administrators to
> easily create complex file conversion processes. The core of Media
> Mover is the media_mover_api module which creates a set of rules
> allowing multiple modules to interact with a file. Media Mover can
> take a file emailed to an email account, turn a file attachment into
> an FLV file, create a new node with the file data, and then save the
> file on an external file storage system like Amazon's S3 all at once.
> And that's just the start.

**What you can do**
The core set of Media Mover modules offers lots of options for someone manipulating rich media.

- get attachments from an email account
- get attached files from nodes of a specified type
- get files from previously harvested files
- get files from CCK filefield and imagefield fields
- get files from a FTP server, provide file tokens for user authentication as well
- create a thumbnail from a video file with ffmpeg
- transcode video files into web friendly (and other) formats
- compress a file with zip
- move a file to Amazon's S3 service
- attach file back to node
- save file and related data as a node
- add a file to a CCK filefield or imagefield
- save a file to YouTube

Answer (score 0):

There is no module like this in my knowledge as I have also searched a lot for the same functionality which you want.

Though the near which I got is, I will upload the folder and all the images will be available to choose when I make gallery.

Thanks,
RajeevK